# Test suite failed to run Cannot find module '@env' from ''mylocalfile.js"

Tags: react-native, jestjs, environment-variables, dotenv

I am using jest unit testing in my project. It was working fine for some time. I have integrated dotenv with my project recently. Now testing is failed for all files. Receiving following error when I do a run test.

[image]

Project dotenv Structure

1. .env in my root folder
2. env.d.ts in my root folder/src/typings

My actual code

```
import { Linking, AsyncStorage, Platform, Alert } from "react-native";
import { Toast } from "native-base";
import { ZOOM_APP_PLAYSTORE, ZOOM_APP_APPSTORE, ZOOM_URL } from "@env";
import { General } from "../Constants";
```

when I do run the app, it is working fine, and issues with only run a test.

Unit testing - jest

Test code

```
describe("Testpage Component", () => {
    it('renders without crashing', () => {
        const rendered = renderer.create(<Provider store={store}>
            <DrawerComponent />
        </Provider>).toJSON();
        expect(rendered).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey did you find a way to fix this issue? I currently facing the same problem.

Comment: This issue came because of the @env library config file so I have removed it completely and used react-native-config instead

Comment: Maintainer of react-native-dotenv here! This is most likely caused by improper babel config. What is your babel config?

Comment: I currently have the following:
module.exports = function (api){
  api.cache(false);
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module:react-native-dotenv', {
        "envName": "APP_ENV",
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": ".env",
      }
      ],
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
    ],
  }
};